# Handle and Design Session Part in Non-Auth Web App

Tags: node.js, session, express, mongoose

I'm creating a web app (Node.js+Express+Mongoose), which is really simple in authentication. It's more like a one-time use app, so there's no user name and password that need user to signup or login.

User A could use the web app when he enter the index page. And he will get a UUID (some ID that looks like a UUID :) ). I want to setup a session module, so that my user A won't get a new UUID when he return to the app in a short time.

And the reason I don't want User A get new UUID is: he can have private talk with other User B/C. And the chat stuff needs his/their UUID to store and retrieve.

Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: Do I need some other info from user like device/browser_id or similar stuff to complete the session module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already understand what is required based on your question

When the user vists the index page, in this case let's say it's '`/`', the page generates a uuid and stores it in the session like so (unless they already have an id assigned to them):

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');

// Basic mongoose session setup
mongoose.connect(connectionOptions);
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// Example index route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if(!req.session.uid) {
      // No uid is set for this user
      req.session.uid = uuid.v1();
      // do something
    } else {
      // uid already exists
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps a lot. But I'm confused about the part of Mongoose session. What does it used for? To store the session somewhere in Mongo?

Comment: Yes, it is just to store the session somewhere. You could use an alternative method such as redis, cookies etc.